# How do I measure the performance impact of antivirus applications?

Tags: macos, performance, anti-virus

I'm evaluating Antivirus software suites for my Mac, and would like to measure the performance impact they have on my computer.

I am not looking to do a expert-level thorough examination, but rather get a crude measure with some snapshot data points (or time-series data if possible).

- What are the main metrics I should monitor? I'm thinking about the application's CPU usage – but is there anything else?
- Is there a user-friendly way to do this (using an application or Terminal tool)?

If there is a general answer that applies to measuring any type of application, perhaps the question title should be changed to *“how to measure the performance impact of MacOS applications”*.

---

*Note: There are of course a few AV comparison sites out there. But I've been slightly perplexed when looking at their results. For instance, one year ESET Cybersecurity Pro gets a top score in the performance department, but the next year it scores much lower and the article will say that it's a drag on the computer. I gather that one way to find out what works is to test them yourself.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/news/news-single-view/12-security-suites-for-mac-os-x-put-to-the-test/) state that their method is to use a large number of files & record the time taken to download, then repeat using each antivirus & see how much it slows down.

> **Partly disappointing system loads**
>
> For the load test of the security packages, 839 files, representing a
>   volume of 30.6 GB, were copied on a reference system, and many
>   downloads were performed. The time needed for these tasks served as
>   the reference value in the test. As soon as a protection solution was
>   installed, it was required to complete the same tasks. The relevant
>   times required are listed in the latest test chart. The results,
>   however, could not be more diverse. The reference time was 246
>   seconds. As already mentioned, the packages from Bitdefender and ESET,
>   with 249 and 253 seconds, hardly put the brakes on the system. The
>   other values from Symantec, Canimaan Software, Kaspersky and AVG are
>   good up to the clocked 268 seconds, however they're not great. But
>   after Sophos with 284 seconds, the values continue to increase
>   significantly: from 292 to 466 for Avast. The nearly unbelievable
>   value of 1387 seconds was measured for Dr. Web. That is more than 5.6
>   times the reference value.

[the referenced chart]

[image]

In my own, less than scientific tests, I could feel the slowdown using Sophos or Avast, long before I read about them on the AV-TEST site.

Regarding system load, they appear to be less specific. One can only imagine they are looking at Activity Monitor, but there's no direct information, only the rather vague

> The two charts with the test results quickly reveal that the
>   protection solutions from Bitdefender and ESET, despite 100% detection
>   rate, cause little or no burden on the system. They require for their
>   own performance a mere 1 to 2% of system resources. Most of the other
>   solutions in fact require up to 10% system resources for security
>   performance, in some cases even m ore.